# check if all the values of list is in dataframe column

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a list which has string values.

Example: `listofwords = ['A, 'B', 'C']` . I have a dataframe with a column. I want my code to return `True` if *all* the values in the list is in that column.

How can I do this?

Comment: i dont know who marked this question as duplicate, but clearly the questions are different. I want to return True/False but the link shared extracts the rows of values in list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create sets for both and take set-compliment, if its empty that means all items of listofwords are in the Dataframe_column:

```
len(set(listofwords) - set(df['Dataframe_Column'])) == 0
```

Comment: If it returns true, does that mean all the elements of my list is in that column?

Comment: i mean the column will have words which are not there in the list as well. But the values in the list should be there in that column

Comment: Yes, it only checks if all values of the list are present in the column (not the other way round)